# How to import module (browser side) in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, requirejs, transpiler

I am trying to import a module from another file in typescript. But I got the following error:

```
scripts.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Rectangle' of undefined(…)
```

Here is my simple module in another file (module.js) but same directory:

```
export module Shapes {  
    export class Rectangle {
        constructor (
            public height: number, 
            public width: number) {
    }
    }

    export var rect1 = new Rectangle(10, 4);
}
```

And the file (scripts.js) that import:

```
import {Shapes} from "./module";

let myshapes:Shapes.Rectangle;

myshapes=new Shapes.Rectangle(1,2);
```

And the index.html

```
<script data-main="scripts" src="./require.js"></script>
```

Any help? I am very lost. The tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

John.

Comment: do you need that surrounding "namespace" "Shapes" around "Rectangle"?

Comment: Not really, it is just to learn how to use module... Obviously, I don't get it. And it does not change nothing. I still have the issue. I think the module file is just not imported.

Comment: if you do not need it then I would suggest to call the file shapes.ts and then do `import {Rectangle} from './shapes'`. I also use this pattern to put classes together. I think "module" is only used for type declarations. I've now learned you could use "namespace" instead of "module": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

Comment: Hum. I think it is not coming from that. If I do what you said, I got the error: " scripts.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: module_1.Rectangle is not a constructor